# Using and embedding extrafonts in PDF in R

Tags: r, pdf

This is my first ever posting here. I am at the end of my tether trying to embed fonts in a PDF chart. I am making figures for a book I have written and this is the last thing! I would like to use Arial font.

I have followed the instructions at http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2012/09/how-to-use-your-favorite-fonts-in-r-charts.html and installed all the fonts. When I type `fonts()`, I get a big list of fonts. Then I try to use them in the chart.

Here is some example code:

```
pdf(file="C:/Users/My R Files/BollTrigPDF2.pdf", width=3.5, height=2.5, family="Arial")
par(mai=c(0.45,0.4,0.2,0), omi=c(0,0,0,0), mgp=c(1.1,0.1,0), tck=-0.015, font.lab=1)
boxplot(df2$pfac[df2$stop<4][df2$stop>1.5]~df2$sdtrig[df2$stop<4][df2$stop>1.5],
        outline=FALSE, xlab="Bollinger Trigger", ylab="Profit Factor",
        cex.axis=0.5, cex.lab=0.7)
dev.off()
```

When I open the PDF that this creates, it looks fine. But when I run `embedFonts()` on it, the fonts are not embedded in the new PDF. If I run `embed_fonts()`, it just hangs until I press Esc.

If, instead, I set the family to "Garamond", the initial PDF has a font that looks pretty-much like Garamond (not sure whether it really is). Then I try to embed the fonts. `embed_fonts()` still does not work, but I can run `embedFonts()` and I get a PDF with the Garamond-like font embedded.

If I set the font family to "Calibri" -- which I tried in case there was a special problem with Arial -- then the initial PDF doesn't have any fonts at all! There is just blank space where the axis labels and tick marks should be.

I am completely confused by all this.

Comment: Did you try helvetica? Arial is a Windows knock-off of it, so if it's the look you're after and you can get helvetica to work, I'd go with it.

Comment: It would be helpful to see your full code for the `embedFonts` call (or better: a reproducible example of the error). A likely problem (from the `embedFonts` help file): If the special font is not installed for Ghostscript, you will need to tell Ghostscript where the font is, using something like options="-sFONTPATH=path/to/font".